# Do pets left alone on a level continue fighting in your absence?

Tags: nethack

I'm standing on a staircase, surrounded by hostiles, with my pets just outside the hostiles. They are helping, but I'm getting low on HP and need to go up to restore. It's going to take a while, and I can't bring my pets with me. Will they continue the fight (possibly, winning or dying)?  Also, might a pets hunger influence its will to fight on?

Answer (score 6):

For the most part, Time is paused when you are not on a level. ([Source 1](http://www.nethack.org/v343/Guidebook.html#_TOCentry_11))

Your pets should only follow you upstairs if they are adjacent to your position when you use the stairs. They will slowly grow feral if you leave them behind on a different level. Your pets only need food to survive, but they should feast on the corpses of enemies that are made of meat. ([Source 2](http://www.nethack.org/v343/Guidebook.html#_TOCentry_17)) Corpses will still rot when you are not on a level, however, and since creatures are frozen in place, your pet probably won't be eating anything while you're gone. ([Source 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/nethack/comments/4r70ay/do_monsters_spawn_on_previously_visited_floors/))

The tameness of a pet depends on how well your pet is treated and fed, and will be affected by how long you spend on another level. Detailed information may be found here:
([Source 4](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~eva/nethack/pets2.html))

Comment: So, they just freeze?  No eating, no fighting, no anything?  Except, losing tameness.

Comment: What about regeneration of hp for pets and monsters, are they just as depleted as you left them?

Comment: Yep, just losing tameness. I'm not sure about HP regeneration, but it shouldn't be too difficult to find out. I know the sourcecode for NetHack is available on Github, but I'm having a bit of trouble deciphering it. :P